# Bootstrap layout JQuery Resize

Tags: javascript, css, html, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap3 for a responsive layout. I am also using JQuery UI to resize the div.

My code snippet looks like this div (class="col-sm-4 ui-widget-content")

When I resize the div I need to size it to the bootstrap 12 col grid pattern. So for example if I resize the div horizontally, I need the class as col-sm-5.

Is there a way to align the grid/assign the class to bootstrap columns?

Thnak you

Comment: please provide some code and create a fiddle of your code

Answer (score 0):

For a CSS solution you would need to establish the breakpoint in which you want the column width to be over-written. So if your saying you want (class="col-sm-4 ui-widget-content") to utilize col-sm-5 width on tablet portrait view (for example), you would need to over-ride the width in your media query by replacing the bootstrap width of col-sm-4 for width of col-sm-5.

Example:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
.col-sm-4 .ui-widget-content {width: 41.66666667% !important;}
}
```

Personally, I'm not sure why you would want to do this. It would be far more beneficial to leverage the bootstrap framework as is and simply fine tune the jQuery UI elements by redefining their widths to (width: auto) or (width: 100%) where needed to ensure they properly fill the bootstrap cols. This would ensure the responsive integrity of your template. Additionally, leveraging jQuery UI themes and images won't provide the visual clarity your looking for as they are not compatible with mobile Retina displays or (@2x). jQuery UI has some cool functionality and widgets but I find customizing your own mobile-friendly theme within bootstrap will give you the best of both.

Hope this helps!